# Remove row of a 2d numpy array if the 2nd element is a not a duplicate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
a = [['I05', 'U13', 4],
     ['I12', 'U13', 5],
     ['I22', 'U13', 3],
     ['I03', 'U15', 5],
     ['I14', 'U23', 5],
     ['I12', 'U23', 2],
     ['I15', 'U43', 5]]
```

Here we have two entries for U13 and three entries for U23. So I need to keep those arrays and remove the rest.

I want a result like this after removing:

```
a = [['I05', 'U13', 4],
     ['I12', 'U13', 5],
     ['I22', 'U13', 3],
     ['I14', 'U23', 5],
     ['I12', 'U23', 2]]
```

How to do this efficiently?

The arrays are already sorted on the second column (the `'UXX'` values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method should achieve the desired output:

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

a = np.array(a)
# count number of occurrences of each value in 2nd col
d = Counter(a[:,1])

# create index where counts > 1
index_keep = [i for i, j in enumerate(a[:,1]) if d[j] > 1]
```

```py
>>> print(a[index_keep])
[['I05' 'U13' '4']
 ['I12' 'U13' '5']
 ['I22' 'U13' '3']
 ['I14' 'U23' '5']
 ['I12' 'U23' '2']]
```

Answer (score 2):

For mixed types, Pandas is a convenient option. Since your data is sorted, you only need to keep duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = np.array([('I05', 'U13', 4),
              ('I12', 'U13', 5),
              ('I22', 'U13', 3),
              ('I03', 'U15', 5),
              ('I14', 'U23', 5),
              ('I12', 'U23', 2),
              ('I15', 'U43', 5)],
            dtype='object, object, i4')

df = pd.DataFrame(A)
B = df[df.duplicated(subset=['f1'], keep=False)].values

print(B)

array([['I05', 'U13', 4],
       ['I12', 'U13', 5],
       ['I22', 'U13', 3],
       ['I14', 'U23', 5],
       ['I12', 'U23', 2]], dtype=object)
```

Note NumPy adds names automatically. This is a structured array, not an array of tuples:

```
print(A)

array([('I05', 'U13', 4), ('I12', 'U13', 5), ('I22', 'U13', 3),
       ('I03', 'U15', 5), ('I14', 'U23', 5), ('I12', 'U23', 2),
       ('I15', 'U43', 5)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', 'O'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Comment: What does the 'f1' do? Can you please elaborate? Also, I have an array of arrays, not an array of tuples. Will it work there?

Comment: @PreetomSahaArko, See update, NumPy automatically adds names. These feed into Pandas.

Comment: @PreetomSahaArko, Also note that `A` is **not** an array of tuples, it's a structured array. You can easily convert to a structured array via the above logic.